# Getting the URL of a frame

Tags: url, frame

I was wondering how to determine which was is the URL of the main frame obtained by typing a ticker symbol on this page:

https://marketviewer.equiduct.com/

For instance, if you type a ticker symbol like 'mlm' on this page, you are brought to a page where there are a number of frames. I am interested in getting the URL of the bigger one, i.e. the one the Bid and the Offer. I am using the chrome browser, but any other browser would suffice.
Thanks in advance.
Arturo.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the page is created with flash, so you can't get any information from something like this.

It could be useful:

- https://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/reading-flash-data
- [Can I scrape flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223624/can-i-scrape-flash)

Comment: I see. Thanks anyhow,